# Asymptotic formula for Prime Numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

My question is:

> Obtain an asymptotic estimate for the sum $$S(x)=\sum_{x<p \leq 2 x} \frac{1}{p}$$ with relative error $1 / \log x$ (i.e., an estimate of the form $$S(x)=f(x)(1+O(1 / \log x))$$ with a simple elementary function $f(x)$.)

I read a (theorem) 4.12 from Apostol's Book.

> **Theorem 4.12.** There is a constant $A$ such that $$\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p}=\log \log x+A+O\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right) \text { for all } x \geq 2$$

I tried to construct this theorem again i made some changes but i couldn't find the solution exactly. Can you help me please?

Comment: $$\sum_{p\le 2x}1/p-\sum_{p\le x}1/p=...$$

Comment: Yes , i know, i have learned it before.thanks so much:) but i couldn't apply the first partial sum. I am not very good at asymptotics. So can you help me please?

Comment: $O(1/\log 2x)-O(1/\log x) = O(1/\log x)$ and $\log\log2x-\log\log x = O(1/\log x)
$

Comment: it's very good explanation. i see it .so what about f(x)?

Comment: i am not sure but can f(x) be a constant function?

Comment: So what your opinion or answer about this question? And Whats your answer to  $\sum_{p \leq 2 x} 1 / p-\sum_{p \leq x} 1 / p=\ldots$ @metamorphy